# find the maximum value of specific rows in a column

Tags: excel, max, row, multiple-columns

I have an excel table like this:

[image]

I want to find the maximum value of "story3" (rows 5,9,13 and ....) in the column "shear X". I mean I should write a formula which finds the row of the "story 3s" and then find the max value of them in the column "shear X"

Comment: Is the column always C for Shear X?  or do will it change and you need to find it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the age of your Excel,

Office 365 Excel and later use MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,"story3")
```

Office 2010 and Later us AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,C1:C100/(A1:A100="story3"),1)
```

Earlier versions this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A100="story3",C1:C100))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

---

If column C is not always the `Shear X` column and you need to find it we can use INDEX(MATCH()) to return the correct Column to the above formulas:

```
INDEX(A:H,0,MATCH("shear X",A2:H2,0))
```

So:

```
=MAXIFS(INDEX(A:H,0,MATCH("shear X",2:2,0)),A:A,"story3")

=AGGREGATE(14,7,INDEX(1:100,0,MATCH("shear X",2:2,0))/(A1:A100="story3"),1)

=MAX(IF(A1:A100="story3",INDEX(1:100,0,MATCH("shear X",2:2,0))))
```